# Phonegap: Uploading Multiple Images in a single request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova

How is it possible to send two image taken from [camera plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera) and POST it to server along with other data.

I first tried the FileTransfer() plugin but it has limitation of just one file at a time. Than I tried using xhr to send two files but I only have DATA_URI from the [camera plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera), how do I convert the DATA_URI into a file object so as to send it to the server?

The image are displaying perfectly fine in the DOM, is it possible to convert it to file object and send it to the server?

Edit: using base64 is causing memory issue in iOS devices so can't use that either

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

```
destinationType: Choose the format of the return value. The default is FILE_URI. Defined in navigator.camera.DestinationType (Number)

Camera.DestinationType = {
    DATA_URL : 0,      // Return image as base64-encoded string
    FILE_URI : 1,      // Return image file URI
    NATIVE_URI : 2     // Return image native URI (e.g., assets-library:// on iOS or content:// on Android)
};
```

If you set the destination type to DATA_URL, you will have access to the base64 encoded version of the image.

You can then simply POST this string, and many other image strings, along with your JSON payload to your webservice for processing.

Comment: Using Base64 is causing memory issue so I am avoiding using Base64. I have updated my question on that, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Then you are stuck, this is really the only way you can send the image through ajax all in one call along with your json payload.  Alternatively, you can first have an ajax POST which returns some type of transaction id.  Then you can use that transaction id to POST the images using native objective c.  You will need to first convert the images to NSDATA. I'm not sure if a plugin for this specific case exists, but it wouldn't be too difficult to write.

Comment: Is there any workaround using the image currently displayed in the DOM?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.  You are asking for an object representation of the image... that would be the base64 version.  If that doesn't suffice you are stuck.  Otherwise you can follow my advice in my comment above.

Comment: You can call ajax many time to upload many file with PhoneGap or use native code to do that.